# Edit texture as 2D array in Xna/MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I want to procedurally generate a `texture2D` by pasting smaller textures as tiles, I've done similar things in Python and MatLab, but do not know how to do that in MonoGame.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191533/monogame-c-assigning-images-to-a-2d-array) is similar to what I need to do, but it generates the texture in the `Draw()` method, which in my case could be a performance hit.

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429219/procedurally-generating-a-texture2d-in-xna-monogame), I want to have something that generates the texture and returns it, so I can initialize it as a field instead of re-generating the texture again every time in `Draw()`.

But I do not know how to edit a `texture2D`, the `SetData()` [method](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.html#Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Graphics_Texture2D_SetData__1_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Nullable_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Rectangle____0___System_Int32_System_Int32_) for `Texture2D` is rather confusing, the new data is of type `T[]`, how do I pass in another `Texture2D` as `T[]`? And what are the `Int32` parameters doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `T` parameter is a convenience in which say, you may pass raw bytes instead of colors.

In short, just stick to `Color[]` for `T[]`, the framework will handle all the details such as computing the stride/pitch and so on when using raw bytes.

In your case you could just do the following:

- use `GetData` to get colors from source tile
- use `SetData` to set a region rectangle the size of source tile in the target texture

To initalize it outside `Draw`, I suppose `LoadContent` could be a good place since `GraphicsDevice` should be not be null at this point.

And if somehow you have to do it in `Draw`, use a simple `bool NeedsRefresh` as a guard, check if it's true, if yes then generate your stuff and set it to false; the code block would run only once.